# send email to users including alert template with list items using visual studio?

Tags: email, splistitem

I don't want to set list alerts when items created or changed.

I want to send email(including alert template and all fields in item) to that user which not configured in sharepoint.

My function for sending email is

```
StringDictionary headers = new StringDictionary();
headers.add("to","toaddress@abc.com");
headers.add("from","fromaddress@abc.com");
headers.add("subject","List Item with alert template");
headers.add("content-type","text/html");
string body="alert template with all fields in item";
SPUtility.SendEmail(web, headers, body);
```

does any one know how to get default alert template with items in body part using visual studio?

so i can send email alert template with items.

Thanks..